# Mostrar datos en una tabla según la entrada del usuario en un input text

Tags: angularjs

Tengo un pequeño proyecto en `AngularJS` con una tabla que muestra mascotas perdidas. La aplicación tiene que permitir buscar mascotas perdidas por una determinada raza, y se me ocurrió poner un `<input type="text">` en el `form` para que el usuario ingrese la raza, y se realice la búsqueda (no vean la parte visual, tengo que aprender `Bootstrap` todavía).

[image: viewLostDogs]
Mi idea es sacar ese botón "Search" y hacer que a medida que el usuario escriba los caracteres en el `<input type="text">` se vaya actualizando la información sola. ¿Hay alguna forma de lograr esto? He estado buscando pero no encontré nada que solucione mi problema.

Les dejo los archivos con los que trabajo:

`index.html`:
[image: index.html]

`main.html`:
[image: main.html]

`MainController`:
[image: MainController.js]

`app.js`:
[image: app.js]

y el servicio (`MascotaService`) que consume `MainController`:
[image: MascotaService]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa `filter` de angular, aquí puedes encontrar mas información: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Y por favor, para la próxima copia y pega tu código para poder ayudarte con ello.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo voy a ver... y gracias por el consejo, lo voy a tener en cuenta para la próxima.